# Dynamic Mod_Rewrite Issue

Tags: php, mysql, html, mod-rewrite

I'm designing a completely database driven site, and honestly are VERY new to mod_rewrite. I've looked for an answer to my question without success.

Here is what i've come up with so far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on`
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php [L]
```

What i'm trying to accomplish is any, and all things after the www.example.com/ part to be passed to php, which will then process it. The above does this, but when I try to add images, and the such in the html, such as the  it just doesn't work, and always shows up as a broken image.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's happening because your image links are resolved by your .htaccess as well.

Try this:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #dont redirect existing files
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Had to take out the #dont redirect existing files portion though.

Comment: Either way, thank you VERY much dir, you're AWESOME!

Comment: Is there by chance a way to make it so that it only allows images to work like that?

Comment: Sure! In that case you would have to change the `RewriteCond` line for this one:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$`

Comment: That will redirect everything to `index.php` except image files with those extensions, but notice that other files like `.css` or `.js` will fail! You will have to add them to this line as well. Hope it helps!